# Insert dummy records for missing weekend data in MySQL/Talend

Tags: mysql, talend

I've an ETL job which processes a raw file into a MySQL DB. While doing some analysis, I realized that I need data for all the days in a month and my data feed only has values for weekdays.

I need a way to insert records for the missing days, with data from the last day. e.g. for Saturday and Sunday, I'd want to use data from Friday. For missing Wednesday, I can use data from Tuesday.

Visually this is what I am looking at:

```
**Day**  **Old Table**  **New Table**
Monday      Record 1    Record 1
Tuesday     Record 2    Record 2
Wednesday   Record 3    Record 3
Thursday    Record 4    Record 4
Friday      Record 5    Record 5
Saturday                Record 5
Sunday                  Record 5
Monday      Record 8    Record 8
Tuesday     Record 9    Record 9
Wednesday   Record 10   Record 10
Thursday    Record 11   Record 11
Friday      Record 12   Record 12
Saturday                Record 12
Sunday                  Record 12
Monday      Record 15   Record 15
```

Could someone recommend me a way?

My vague thoughts are converging around working with three datasets:

1) Temp data set with all the date values in it (say start of year till end of year)

2) Original Data which contains missing records (dtst 1)

3) New data, which has all the values (dtst 2)

I don't know how to but if I could loop through all the values in the temp dataset (dtst 1), pull value against the date from the original data and push it in the new dataset (dtst 2). If I don't identify a value in dtst 1, I use the last row fetched from the dtst 1 and push it in the dtst 2. At the end of the loop execution, I'll have data for all the dates in my dtst 2, which I can later use for my analysis.

Comment: What's your primary key?

Answer (score 0):

You could put tJavaRow before Mysql component, then check for empty data in current row, while also saving previously transferred value in a globalMap variable to fill the empty value with.

Answer (score 0):

[tMemorizeRows](https://help.talend.com/reader/mjoDghHoMPI0yuyZ83a13Q/0oEBI6YCTFXSgc5Z9Gpr6Q) is what you're looking for !

> tMemorizeRows temporarily memorizes an array of incoming data in a row by row sequence and instantiates this array by indexing each of the memorized rows from 0. The maximum number of rows to be memorized at any given time is defined in the Basic settings view.

In the component settings, you specify the number of rows to memorize, and the columns you want to memorize. In a `tMap`, you can check the current row value, and if it's empty, retrieve the value that was memorized by `tMemorizeRows`.
You can refer to the column like:
`<columnName>_tMemorizeRows_1[0]` for the current value, `<columnName>_tMemorizeRows_1[1]` for the previous row..etc.